# Writing a machine learning classifier algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was trying to write a classifier algorithm for a machine learning model but it comes with an error. Could anyone help? thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euc(a, b):
        return distance.euclidean(a,b)

class classifierKN():
    def fit(self, X_train, Y_train):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.Y_train = Y_train
        
    def predict(self, X_test):
        predictions = []
        for row in X_test:
            label = self.closest(row)
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions
    def closest(self, row):
        best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train[0])
        best_index = 0
        for i in range(1, len(self.X_train)):
            dist = euc(row, self.X_train[i])
            if dist < best_dist:
                best_dist = dist
                best_index = i
        return self.Y_train[best_index]

#Load the dataset 
diabetdata = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")

#set features and target
features = ["PlasmaGlucose", "DiastolicBloodPressure", "TricepsThickness", "SerumInsulin"]
X = diabetdata[features]
print("FEATURES: " , X.head())

Y = diabetdata.Diabetic
print("TARGET: " , Y.head())
print("")




from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  #No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation' so I replace it with model_selection
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)



#predict 
model= classifierKN()
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
predictKN = model.predict(X)
print ("Predict result with KNeighborsClassifier")
print(predictKN)

#accuracy
print("Accuracy")
print (accuracy_score(Y, predictKN))
```

**Outcome**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\Machine learning\Machine Learning\coursework\test2.py", line 63, in <module>
    predictKN = model.predict(X)

  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\Machine learning\Machine Learning\coursework\test2.py", line 26, in predict
    label = self.closest(row)

  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\Machine learning\Machine Learning\coursework\test2.py", line 30, in closest
    best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train[0])

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Remove the [0] index?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Trace the values that led to the crash.  Include the actual error, not the follow-up error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code actually has several issues at once, so making sense of it is a bit difficult.
Your issues mainly seem to be related to your understanding of pandas Dataframes/Series, as you are apparently trying to iterate over the rows of your dataframe with:

```
def predict(self, X_test):
        predictions = []
        for row in X_test:
            label = self.closest(row)
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions
```

This doesn't work in pandas. To actually iterate over the values of the rows, you would need something like:

```
def predict(self, X_test):
        predictions = []
        for row in X_test.iterrows():
            label = self.closest(list(row[1]))
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions
```

This function does actually iterate over the rows in your dataframe and gives the values of the row into the `closest()` Function.`

```
def closest(self, row):
        best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train[0])
        best_index = 0
        for i in range(1, len(self.X_train)):
            dist = euc(row, self.X_train[i])
            if dist < best_dist:
                best_dist = dist
                best_index = i
        return self.Y_train[best_index]
```

This function doesn't work however, as you basically trying to get the values of row[0] with `best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train[0])`. This simply throws you a keyError, as X_train is a Dataframe and doesn't have a column 0 (You don't want to index that column anyway). What you want is a default best_dist as the distance between your input row and the first row in the dataframe. This would work with something like
`best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train.iloc[0])`.
You then need to iterate over the rows in X_train (here your function has the same problems as before), so you would need to change it into something like:

```
def closest(self, row):
    best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train.iloc[0])
    best_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(self.X_train.index)):
        dist = euc(row, list(self.X_train.iloc[i]))
        if dist < best_dist:
            best_dist = dist
            best_index = i
    return self.Y_train.iloc[best_index]
```

This at least works. Whether or not it gives you the desired Outputs and/or is accurate enough, i cannot guarantuee, but it does resolve your immediate issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Everything makes sense!